# spark scala cartesian product of each element in a column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a dataframe which is like :

```
df:

col1    col2
a       [p1,p2,p3]
b       [p1,p4]
```

Desired output is that:

```
df_out:

col1 col2 col3
p1   p2   a
p1   p3   a
p2   p3   a
p1   p4   b
```

I did some research and i think that converting `df` to `rdd` and then `flatMap` with `cartesian` product are ideal for the problem. However i could not combine them together.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to do combination rather than cartesian.   Please check my understanding.

This is in PySpark but the only python thing is the UDF, the rest is just DataFrame operations.

process is

1. Create dataframe
2. define UDF to get all pairs of combinations ignoring order
3. use UDF to convert array into array of pairs of structs, one for each element of the combination
4. explode the results to get rows of pair of structs
5. select each struct and original column 1 into desired result columns

```
from itertools import combinations
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([
                            ("a", ["p1", "p2", "p3"]),
                            ("b", ["p1", "p4"])
  ],
  ["col1", "col2"]
)

# define and register udf that takes an array and returns an array of struct of two strings
@udf("array<struct<_1: string, _2: string>>")
def combinations_list(x):
   return combinations(x, 2)

resultDf = df.select("col1", F.explode(combinations_list(df.col2)).alias("combos"))

resultDf.selectExpr("combos._1 as col1", "combos._2 as col2", "col1 as col3").show()
```

Result:

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|  p1|  p2|   a|
|  p1|  p3|   a|
|  p2|  p3|   a|
|  p1|  p4|   b|
+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry for the late answer, i changed my whole scala code to pyspark. Your answer works well. Thanks a lot!